# cloudant badmatch error when using deisgn document but the same query works when not using views

Tags: cloudant, enoent

Can someone please help me resolve the query error when using views?
I run this inside cloudant docker container where this issue shows up intermittently.  I cannot reproduce the problem on all container starts but wanted to check how to resolve this without having to delete and re-create the container. Appreciate any help.

curl --user admin:pass  "http://localhost:/basic/_design/example/_view/foo"
{"error":"badmatch","reason":"{error,enoent}","ref":2451670243}

curl --user admin:pass  "http://localhost:/basic/_design/example" 
{"_id":"_design/example","_rev":"1-230141dfa7e07c3dbfef0789bf11773a","views":{"foo":{"map":"function(doc){ emit(doc._id, doc._rev)}"}}}